# Mac Lync 2011 will not connect to my Office 365 account

Tags: macos, mac, lync, office365

With valid credentials that work on a Windows Lync client, I am able to log in, but not using Mac Lync 2011.  The error I get is that credentials are invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hotfix from Microsoft fixes the problem

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36517

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Lync 2011 configuration settings are manually set to the following :

```
Internal server name : sipdir.online.lync.com:443
External server name : sipdir.online.lync.com:443
```

You can refer to the following guide [Lync 2011 troubleshooting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2629861)